# Convert .mp4 to .webm on react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-camera

i am using expo-camera to record a video but the uri response comes with a .mp4 url, is there a way to convert .mp4 to webm?, just by changing the type to video/webm is not enough once my video, on expo camera documentation i had no lucky

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/

````
      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('videoFile', {
        uri: video.uri,
        name: video.uri,
        type: 'video/mp4',
      })

      console.log(JSON.stringify(formData))

      setVideo('')
    }```
````

Comment: Not a lot of camera software takes webm as a native format.  You'd need to find converter software, and converting it may be expensive in terms of time and memory.

Comment: thank you Gabe, we talked to them and it would cost a lot of processing to some users according to their cellphone specifications, i am sending as mp4 and backend will deal with it, thanks for the reply